# cant install new nods in embed node-red

Tags: node-red

Embedding into an existing app

https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/runtime/embedding

so when go to Manage palette and Install any new nodes I see Error in Editor

> Failed to install: node-red-contrib-ui-svg

> Cannot find module 'node-red-contrib-ui-svg

> Check the log for more information

and this full log :

```
2021-03-07T10:26:01.901Z Install : node-red-contrib-ui-svg 2.2.1

2021-03-07T10:26:01.910Z npm.cmd install --no-audit --no-update-notifier --no-fund --save --save-prefix=~ --production node-red-contrib-ui-svg@2.2.1
2021-03-07T10:26:10.448Z [err] npm notice
2021-03-07T10:26:10.449Z [err]  created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
2021-03-07T10:26:10.450Z [out] + node-red-contrib-ui-svg@2.2.1
2021-03-07T10:26:10.450Z [out] added 29 packages from 28 contributors in 6.044s
2021-03-07T10:26:10.488Z rc=0
```

but when checking new installed nodes in editor cant show its .
and after restart node-red same issus
this my nodejs app:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require("express");
var RED = require("node-red");


// Create an Express app
var app = express();

// Add a simple route for static content served from 'public'
app.use("/", express.static("public"));


// Create a server
var server = http.createServer(app);


// Create the settings object - see default settings.js file for other options
var settings = {
    httpAdminRoot: "/red1",
    httpNodeRoot: "/api",
    userDir: "./hhh",
    functionGlobalContext: {} // enables global context
};



// Initialise the runtime with a server and settings

RED.init(server, settings);


// Serve the editor UI from /red
app.use(settings.httpAdminRoot, RED.httpAdmin);


// Serve the http nodes UI from /api
app.use(settings.httpNodeRoot, RED.httpNode);


server.listen(8005);


// Start the runtime
RED.start();
```

```
node-red : v1.2.9-git
npm -v : 6.14.4
node -v : v12.16.3
```

Comment: The log output implies that the install has succeeded. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66515932/edit) the question to show how you've set up the embedded instance and where you've put things like the `userDir`

Comment: And if you look under `.hhh` the SVG node is present? Also what version of Node-RED, nodejs and npm are you using?

Comment: yes its found, PATH: .hhh\node_modules\node-red-contrib-ui-svg. and my version
node-red : v1.2.9-git, 
npm -v : 6.14.4, 
node -v : v12.16.3,

Comment: Is this you? https://discourse.nodered.org/t/i-cant-install-any-nodes-in-embedded-node-red/41791 If so please continue to work on this on discourse, posting it here as well will just split the effort.

Comment: I made it here for not receiving a response from the forum. ok thanks to replay

Answer (score 0):

thanks to hardillb
its solved

> Please run the following 2 tests:
> Use the full path to the userDir in the settings object: D:\Project\node-red-template embedded\hhh